# OOP Basics: Creating overridden object in base-ctor from derived class

Tags: c#, oop

Sorry for the bad headline, but my english isn't that good.
Assume the following code (use LINQPad in Program-mode for testing):

```
public class BaseClass
{
    protected Settings settings;

    public BaseClass()
    {
        this.settings = new Settings();
    }

    public virtual void PrintSettings()
    {
        var t = settings.GetType();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", t.GetProperties().Select(pi => pi.Name)));
    }

    public class Settings
    {
        public string BaseClassSetting { get { return "BaseClassSetting."; } }
    }
}
```

Calling "new BaseClass().PrintSettings();" will obviously output "BaseClassSetting" in Console.
Let's derive a class from out BaseClass:

```
public class InheritedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new class Settings : BaseClass.Settings
    {
        public string InheritedClassSetting { get { return "InheritedClassSetting!"; } }
    }
}
```

Calling "new InheritedClass().PrintSettings();" will still print "BaseClassSetting" in Console.
The only way to make the code use the "new"ed InheritedClass.Settings is by adding a ctor like

```
public InheritedClass()
{
    this.settings = new Settings();
}
```

With this additional ctor, it prints the desired "InheritedClassSetting, BaseClassSetting" to console.
Now the question: is it possible to make the BaseClass-ctor always use the Settings-Class of the instance's object? (without adding the ctor in the derived class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bad practices, expect bad workarounds for problems. I wouldn't use the `new` keyword in general, never mind for a nested class. You can remove the constructor in your inherited class by making your base class accept a generic type inheriting from `BaseClass.Settings` and with a parameterless constructor. Clearly, it's unreadable.

```
public class BaseClass<T> where T : BaseClass<T>.Settings, new()
{
    protected Settings settings;

    public BaseClass()
    {
        settings = new T();
    }

    public virtual void PrintSettings()
    {
        var t = settings.GetType();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", t.GetProperties().Select(pi => pi.Name)));
    }

    public class Settings
    {
        public string BaseClassSetting
        {
            get { return "BaseClassSetting."; }
        }
    }
}

public class InheritedClass : BaseClass<InheritedClass.Settings>
{
    public new class Settings : BaseClass<InheritedClass.Settings>.Settings
    {
        public string InheritedClassSetting
        {
            get { return "InheritedClassSetting!"; }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that on the line:

```
public new class Settings : BaseClass<InheritedClass.Settings>.Settings
```

The arguments for the generics don't require you to specify `InheritedClass`. I've added it because it's pretty confusing already, I didn't want to make it worse.

Comment: Nice, but truly not very readable ;-) What would be your approach for solving this task?

Comment: @Sascha Depends on how you'll use your classes. For example, if inheritance, is not necessary, I'd just use an interface both for what you called `BaseClassSettings` and `InheritedSettings` (but not make one derive from the other). Also, I'd avoid declaring them as a nested class, if not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

No, because you cannot have "virtual types".

There are several ways that you could try to achieve what you are doing here, but all of them would require `InheritedClass` to explicitly refer to its own version of `Settings` at some point.